# Como obter as coordenadas de um ponto a determinada distância da minha localização?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Fala galera, estou fazendo um app, e em uma activity do app preciso a partir da minha localização dar um "zoom" no maps conforme o usuário desliza uma seekBar, conforme a imagem.

[image: Activity]

Estive pensando em usar o recurso Bounds no maps, onde consigo passar duas longitudes e latitudes para que o maps crie uma borda e o zoom.

```
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                    .include(providerLocation)
                    .include(myLocation)
                    .build();
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, getWidthScreen()-0, getHeightScreen()-0, 190));
```

O meu problema é o seguinte, não estou conseguindo calcular a partir do meu ponto a latitude de um ponto x1, um ponto x2, que seriam os pontos de referencias.

Agradeço a ajuda de todos !!!

Answer (score 6):

Se o que pretende é calcular um *Bounds* que tenha um raio(meia diagonal) igual ao indicado pela *seekBar* e que a sua localização esteja no centro, faça assim.

```
//Calcula o ponto à distância 'raio' do 'centro*' na direção 45º(canto superior direito)
LatLng norhtEast = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(centro, raio, 45);

//Calcula o ponto à distância 'raio' do 'centro' na direção 225º(canto inferior esquerdo)
LatLng southWest = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(centro, raio, 225);

LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(southWest,norhtEast);
```

Onde:

**centro** -  LatLng da sua posição.
**raio** - Distância, em metros, do centro aos cantos superior direito e inferior esquerdo do *Bounds*

Comment: tenho que dar uma pesquisada neste SphericaUtil, pra ver se é isso mesmo. Bom consegui, porém seria melhor um calculo exato que realizasse o espaçamento do meu centro ao canto em diagonal do maps.

Comment: O CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds() não fez isso?

Comment: bom, estou utilizando ele para redefinir a câmera, e dar o zoom, porém antes tenho passar o bounds para ele, e é nisso que estou travando, tenho que calcular um LatLng da posição esquerda e um da posição direita, ai incluo no bounds e após passo como parâmetro no CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds().

Comment: O que estou perguntando é se o `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds()` com o *Bound* calculado da forma que eu indiquei não fez isso?

Comment: Faz sim, com o Bound caculado, porém com esse calculo não gerou o zoom requerido.

Comment: Experimente usar assim `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 0);`