# Com esta regra, como faço para visualizar o ponto mais perto da minha localização

Tags: android, maps

```
Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonComoChegar);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String latitude = itemPosicao.getLatitude();
        String longitude = itemPosicao.getLongitude();

        String strUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + latitude + "," + longitude;
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strUri));

        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

#### Esta lista esta buscando a latitude e longitude do Banco, o que eu tava querendo é que apareça o usuário mais próximo de mim pela latitude e longitude.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possivel duplicata [Cálculo para obter a longitude e latitude a partir da minha localização](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57282/c%C3%A1lculo-para-obter-a-longitude-e-latitude-a-partir-da-minha-localiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o?rq=1)

Comment: isso não resolve...

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13061/como-resgatar-a-localiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-gps-em-coordenadas-de-todos-os-usu%C3%A1rios-do-aplicati

Comment: Tipo, eu tenho uma listview mostrando alguns usuários e que lá mostra o um botão para ir ao local do usuário, só que esta lista queria mostrar do ponto mais perto ou seja, se cima para baixo sem o usuário saber. A lista mostraria os usuários mais perto.

Answer (score 0):

Calculando a distância entre 2 pontos

```
public static double distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
double earthRadius = 3958.75; // miles (or 6371.0 kilometers)
double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
double sindLat = Math.sin(dLat / 2);
double sindLng = Math.sin(dLng / 2);
double a = Math.pow(sindLat, 2) + Math.pow(sindLng, 2)
        * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2));
double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
double dist = earthRadius * c;

return dist;
}
```

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120283/how-can-i-measure-distance-and-create-a-bounding-box-based-on-two-latitudelongi

Voce pode verificar também esse  link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577075/calculating-the-distance-between-two-latitude-and-longitude-points-in-android